# How to test whether a sequence of integers was randomly generated?

Tags: java

So I am trying to test if a sequence of integers was randomly generated, but it doesn't work... 
this is what I've got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] sequence = { r.nextInt(), r.nextInt(), r.nextInt() };
    System.out.println(isRandomSequence(sequence));
}

public static boolean isRandomSequence(int[] sequence) {
    for (long seed = 0; seed < Long.MAX_VALUE; ++seed) {
        Random r = new Random(seed);
        long tries = 0;
        for (int i = 0; tries < Long.MAX_VALUE; ++tries) {
            if (sequence[i] == r.nextInt()) {
                if (++i == sequence.length) return true;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: to clarify; I want to know if, for instance the sequence { 4, 5, 6 } was generated by the random number generator. For starters limiting the testing to the java.util.Random (would be nice to have a general solution though if it's possible).

Comment: Can you be more specific on  'it doesnt work'?

Comment: Could you define for us what your acceptable measure of randomness is?

Comment: You do realize that the body of the inner loop is to be executed 85070591730234615847396907784232501249 (~8.5e37) times?

Comment: "randomly generated" is a statement about the process that resulted in the numbers.  It cannot be tested by looking at the numbers.  You can check if a sequence "appears to be randomly generated" using statistical methods.

Comment: I would recommend reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: No offence, but I think you need to take a step back and explain what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you want to run the diehard tests on the random number generator.  Someone already has: http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/04/03/a-java-programmers-guide-to-random-numbers-part-1-beyond-javautilrandom/

Answer (score 4):

Apart from being intractable, your brute-force technique will only detect a pseudorandom sequence generated by `java.util.Random`, by far not the only option to generate pseudorandom numbers. Also note the word **pseudo**: they are not really random, that is why you think you can detect the sequence.

Detecting whether a sequence is truly random is theoretically impossible: the best you can do is perform a barrage of pattern-detecting tests in order to eliminate *certain* possibilities. There will always be nonrandom sequences that escape detection.

I should also note that there is definitely nothing to say about a sequence of just three integers. I am pretty sure that the output of `java.util.Random` contains all possible three-integer sequences.

Comment: Pseudo yes, but more than capable of generating sufficiently random sequences.  I think the existing Random is more than adequate.  The issue is a poor understanding of how it works and a bad implementation for generating sequences.

Comment: @duffymo - he isn't trying to generate - he is trying to test!

Comment: I understand, but I'm guessing that he wants to test because he tried an implementation that was flawed.  Rather than suspect his random sequence generation code, he's assuming that the Random class is wrong and needs to be verified.

Comment: @duffymo His mission is quite mundane in fact: he wants to reverse-engineer a sequence of ints to see if it is the result of repeated invocations of `Random.nextInt()` with an unknown seed and an unknown starting element.

Comment: I suspect that it's worse than that, because of the code he posted.  No one in their right mind would create new Random instances with new seeds in that loop.  It made me think that the original source of sequences was wrong.  But perhaps you're right - I'm not a good mind reader.

Comment: I thought of that except there are 2^96 possible three int values and only 2^48 seeds.  The changes that such a sequence happens to be the same as one generated using Random is 1/(2^48) to one or 1 in 256 million million.

Answer (score 2):

Random only has 2^48 seeds.  This means you "only" need explore 2^48 seeds from the start. no more.

All the same, exploring 2^48 seeds will take hours or days to run.

As this is very cpu intensive you could look at using all the CPUs you have available ;)

Comment: So how do I know what seeds to test? Could you give an example?

Comment: You can call setSeed repeatedly from 0 to 2^48-1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about the way seed works incorrectly.  That might explain why you aren't getting random sequences.

You don't seed every time.  You instantiate the Random with the seed at the start of your process and hang onto it.

If you create a Random inside a method call, with a new seed every time you want a sequence, you're definitely doing it *wrong*.

I'll bet this works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * RandomSequenceGenerator
 * @author mduffy
 * @since 12/12/12 4:38 PM
 */
public class RandomSequenceGenerator {

    private Random random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomSequenceGenerator generator = new RandomSequenceGenerator();
        int numSequences = ((args.length > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : 10);
        int lenSequence  = ((args.length > 1) ? Integer.valueOf(args[1]) : 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < numSequences; ++i) {
            System.out.println(generator.createRandomSequence(lenSequence));
        }
    }

    public RandomSequenceGenerator() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public RandomSequenceGenerator(long seed) {
        this.random = new Random(seed);
    }

    public synchronized List<Integer> createRandomSequence(int length) {
        List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            sequence.add(this.random.nextInt());
        }
        return sequence;
    }
}
```